# C++ function and rvalue confusion

Tags: c++, rvalue

with reference to the following code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct S
{
    S()
    {
        cout << "ctor\n";
    }
    S(S&& rhs)
    {
        cout << "called move\n";
    }
};

S goo()
{
    S a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{

 S&& goo();
 cout << "before construction\n";
 S a = goo();

}
//http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html
```

why is the code calling the `move constructor` and not the function `S goo()`? If you comment out the first line then it does not.

why is the return type of `S goo()` different depending on the first line in `main`? I dont think this should even compile but compiles here 
http://cpp.sh/22zeq

(does not compile on wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3YxBdcWs91FRiODG)

was reading an example on here: http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html
when i stumbled upon this

Comment: What do you think `S&& goo();` does in your main?

Comment: @SergeyA here is no definition for `S&& goo()` so how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Since everybody seems to be in understanding of what `S&& goo();` in main does (it declares a function) but people seem to not understand how `S goo()` get's called in the end.

The reason for this is the fact that return value is not part of function signature. So when you call `goo()`, you end up calling the only version of it which is available - one returning `S`. I believe, this is an example of undefined behavior.

Comment: @SergeyA No, I believe OP is referring to how the compiler is letting such an ambiguous overload even be declared.  It can be defined in another translation unit yes, but its not viable to be overloaded in the first place.  Clang rejects the code correctly https://wandbox.org/permlink/pwYSWrxoHNLEDOs6

Comment: @Curious I believe it is undefined behavior, but I have no quote to prove it.

Comment: @SergeyA I would think that overloading functions wrongly based on the return types should be well defined in the standard to lead to ill formed code.. I will try and look into this

Answer (score 1):

It is because `S&& goo();` is declaration of *new function*.
But when you compile it exists only one function with such name `S goo();` that is why it was called.

It is a work of linker. It has not found any another function with such name and linked it to `S goo();`

Comment: there is no definition for `S&& goo()` so how does it work?

Comment: @pyjg It is easy. When happens call of function compiler added in this place of call symbolic name goo. Then linker try to find by signature a function and find S goo() and then replaced it with address of this function. This issue happens because return value is not part of signature of function

Comment: @pyjg This happens because for compiler it is another function, but for linker exists only one such function `goo()` [ `S goo()` ]

Comment: hmm isnt this a bug then?

Comment: @pyjg No it is not. It is some kind of specific of C++ language. Compiler works properly. It consider last declaration of function in local scope. If you move `S&& goo()` outside it will consider call of `goo()` as ambiguous. It is an issue of whole language as for me

Comment: @DenisKotov the language does not allow this to compile, i think this is an issue with the compiler https://wandbox.org/permlink/pwYSWrxoHNLEDOs6

Answer (score 1):

The return type is different because `S&& goo();` is a *function declaration*. So, it *does not* construct anything.

It tells the compiler that `goo` is a function that returns `S&&` and takes no arguments. This overwrites any other previous declarations, so, for the `main` function, `goo` returns a `S&&`. When you comment that line out, only the function definition defines the return type.

This also works on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/O1ihCI). That is, inside `main` the return type of `goo` has changed to `S&&`.